# Strange wrapping with lists and floats

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

http://jsfiddle.net/cqEw2/

Markup:

```
<section>
    <h1>Title of this section</h1>

    <ol>
        <li>Thing thing thing thing thing thing thing thing</li>
        <li>Thing Thing Thing Thing THING THING THING</li>
    </ol>

    <nav>
        <ol>
            <li>Place1</li>
            <li>PlaceThatIsSecond</li>
            <li>Place3</li>
            <li>Place4</li>
            <li>Place5</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Styles:

```
section > ol {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        clear: both;
        max-width: 80%;
}

section > nav {
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

As you shrink the window, there comes a point where the long item causes the rest of the list to be pushed under the main content, but earlier list items on the left are still above.  Really the whole thing should go down at once, or possibly just continue to shrink.  I do not encounter this behaviour with similar sidebar styles that use paragraphs and blockquotes.  Is this something particular to the way my browser chooses to layout lists, or is it in the standard and I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a position:absolute; it should solve the problem of the main content being pushed underneath.

```
section > ol {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 80%;
}
section > nav {
   max-width: 20%;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I set it to position:absolute then it will be taken out of flow inside the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Change `section > ol` to `section ol` to ensure the block is applied to both `ol` elements.

Comment: That will float the nav list, which is very much not what I want.